# DataGridViewImageColumn triggers exception when assigning cell Value

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

Have C# form with DataGridView with first column being DataGridViewImageColumn. In form constructor, Add rows to DataGridView, with first argument being a Bitmap object read from a file. DataGridView displays correctly, no problems.

```
Bitmap blackCamera = null;
Bitmap grayCamera = null;
public FormConstructor()
{
    ...
    blackCamera = new Bitmap(@"BlackCamera.bmp");
    grayCamera = new Bitmap(@"GrayCamera.bmp");
    ...
    int row = dataGridView_xxx.Rows.Add(blackCamera); // works fine
    ...
    dataGridView_xxx.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = grayCamera; // works fine
    ...
}
```

Later, want to change image for some row's first column cell.
Inside a callback for a mouse function, if attempt to assign the DataGridViewImageColumn cell Value, I get exception "unable to cast object of type System.Drawing.Bitmap to type System.String" but the image does change to the desired new bitmap. For example:

```
private void MouseCallback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    dataGridView_xxx.Rows[nnn].Cells[0].Value = blackCamera; // changes image color but triggers exception
    ...
}
```

Microsoft documentation appears to support assigning DataGridViewImageColumn cell value as above. Curiously, it works without exception in the constructor, but works with exception in the callback.
How to eliminate the exception?

Comment: what exception you got ?

Comment: I setup to catch ThreadExceptionEventHandler, which caught the message I show above.

Comment: type of `dataGridView_xxx.Rows[nnn].Cells[0].Value` is string ?

Comment: Sorry, but how is type of xxx.Value set to string or any specific object? Assignment of Value to Bitmap in constructor is successful w/o exception, but assignment of Value to Bitmap in mouse callback is successful with exception. How did the framework decide Value flipped from Bitmap to string?

Comment: Inserted dataGridView_xxx...Value.GetType() before each assignment of Value and always returns System.Drawing.Bitmap. There appears to be something in the framework that thinks the Mouse Callback assignment is somehow to System.String though GetType of the destination object says otherwise.

Comment: I'm afraid it's all my fault.
I disabled my own ThreadExceptionEvent handler, and the resultant popup from the framework disclosed that dataGridView_xxx_CellValueChanged was being called as a result of my changing the image Value of the DataGridViewImageColumn cell, and that code was attempting to read the changed cell as string, and that triggered the exception. The image column is a new addition to the program, so previously all cell changes were string type. I've modified dataGridView_xxx_CellValueChanged to not worry about DataGridViewImageColumn changes and no exceptions now occur.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. See my final comment above.